# Is there a way to turn off Auto Fill for users when filling out a form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I think this is a quick one for you, Folks:

I am collecting data in a UiApp built form, and using validation before enabling them to continue.  My problem is that often auto-fill will have different format than what is required in my form (such as the state written out instead of a postal abbreviation). I think this may lead to confusion, so I would love to force the users to fill out each box by hand.

Is there a way to turn off the auto-fill function of browsers? 
If I were to build in html, would it give me more control of this?

Thanks for the help~
Martin

NOTE: I am using the "ChangeHandler" as it will at least update the validator when autofill is used.

Here's an example code which is of the style I am using. It includes multiple field validation and a review panel. Relevant to my question, but also may be useful for those building forms.

```
function doGet(e){
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Review and Validation");
var appPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
var form = app.createFormPanel();
var panel1 = app.createGrid(4,5).setId('panel1');

var firstNameLabel = app.createLabel("First Name:");
var firstName = app.createTextBox().setName('firstName').setId('firstName');
var lastNameLabel = app.createLabel("Last Name:");
var lastName = app.createTextBox().setName('lastName').setId('lastName');
var emailLabel = app.createLabel('Your Email');
var email = app.createTextBox().setName('email').setId('email');
var button1 = app.createButton('Go to Review').setEnabled(false);
var info1 = app.createLabel("Please Enter First Name")
.setVisible(false)
.setStyleAttribute('color', 'red');
var info2 = app.createLabel("Please Enter Last Name")
.setVisible(false)
.setStyleAttribute('color', 'red');
var info3 = app.createLabel("Please Enter Email")
.setVisible(false)
.setStyleAttribute('color', 'red');


var syncChangeHandler = app.createServerHandler('syncText').addCallbackElement(form)
.validateLength(firstName, 2, 30).validateLength(lastName, 2, 30).validateEmail(email);

var onValidInput = 
app.createClientHandler().validateLength(firstName,2,30).validateLength(lastName,2,30).validateEmail(email).forTargets(
      button1).setEnabled(true);

var onInvalidInput1 = 
app.createClientHandler().validateNotLength(firstName, 2, 30).forTargets(button1).setEnabled(false).forTargets(info1).setVisible(true);

var onValidInput1 = 
app.createClientHandler().validateLength(firstName, 2, 30).forTargets(info1).setVisible(false);

var onInvalidInput2 = 
app.createClientHandler().validateNotLength(lastName, 2, 30).forTargets(button1).setEnabled(false).forTargets(info2).setVisible(true);

var onValidInput2 = 
app.createClientHandler().validateLength(lastName, 2, 30).forTargets(info2).setVisible(false);

var onInvalidInput3 = 
app.createClientHandler().validateNotEmail(email).forTargets(button1).setEnabled(false).forTargets(info3).setVisible(true);

var onValidInput3 = 
app.createClientHandler().validateEmail(email).forTargets(info3).setVisible(false);

firstName.addChangeHandler(onInvalidInput1);
firstName.addChangeHandler(onValidInput1);

lastName.addChangeHandler(onInvalidInput2);
lastName.addChangeHandler(onValidInput2);

email.addChangeHandler(onInvalidInput3);
email.addChangeHandler(onValidInput3);

firstName.addChangeHandler(onValidInput);
lastName.addChangeHandler(onValidInput);
email.addChangeHandler(onValidInput);

panel1.setWidget(0,0, firstNameLabel);
panel1.setWidget(0,1, firstName);
panel1.setWidget(0,2, lastNameLabel);
panel1.setWidget(0,3, lastName);
panel1.setWidget(1,1, info1);
panel1.setWidget(1,3, info2);
panel1.setWidget(2,0, emailLabel);
panel1.setWidget(2,1, email);
panel1.setWidget(2,3, button1);
panel1.setWidget(3,1, info3);

app.add(form);
appPanel.add(panel1);
form.add(appPanel);


var panel2 = app.createGrid(4,5).setId('panel2').setVisible(false);
var reviewFirstNameLabel = app.createLabel("First Name:");
var reviewFirstName = app.createLabel().setId('reviewFirstName');
var reviewLastNameLabel = app.createLabel("Last Name:");
var reviewLastName = app.createLabel().setId('reviewLastName');
var reviewEmailLabel = app.createLabel('Your Email:');
var reviewEmail = app.createLabel().setId('reviewEmail');
var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('Submit');
var button2 = app.createButton('Edit Response');

panel2.setWidget(0,0, reviewFirstNameLabel); 
panel2.setWidget(0,1, reviewFirstName); 
panel2.setWidget(0,2, reviewLastNameLabel);
panel2.setWidget(0,3, reviewLastName);
panel2.setWidget(1,0, reviewEmailLabel);
panel2.setWidget(1,1, reviewEmail);
panel2.setWidget(2,0, button2);
panel2.setWidget(3,0, submitButton);
appPanel.add(panel2);

//
var editResponse = app.createClientHandler()
.forTargets(panel1).setVisible(true)
.forTargets(panel2).setVisible(false);

button1.addClickHandler(syncChangeHandler);
button2.addClickHandler(editResponse);

return app;
}

function syncText(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 


  app.getElementById('reviewFirstName').setText(e.parameter.firstName);
  app.getElementById('reviewLastName').setText(e.parameter.lastName);
  app.getElementById('reviewEmail').setText(e.parameter.email);
  app.getElementById('panel1').setVisible(false);
  app.getElementById('panel2').setVisible(true);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aiapuj1KtAujdHYzZzNzMEsxMUtranZhaXhiSFFnanc').getSheets()[0];
var range = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1,4);

var values = [[new Date(),e.parameter.firstName, e.parameter.lastName, e.parameter.email]];
range.setValues(values);

var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var label = app.createLabel('Thank You!');
app.add(label);

return app;
}
```

Comment: happy to see that you solved your 'review' problem ;-)

Comment: Your kind to say that I solved it.  More like you and Srik solved it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAS is globally browser independent since the app is running on Google's Server and doesn't interact directly with your browser... I don't think it is possible to tell the browser to do anything like that and I haven't seen any trick that would make that possible... If I'm wrong then I'd be very curious about it ;-)

Edit : I played with your code and I was wondering if it might not be a solution to use a key press handler instead of click handler so users would be forced to use keyboard to fill the form instead of mouse click. I've seen scripts that check if an 'enter' was pressed to validate an answer. (just an idea) 
EDIT 2 : Well, Browsers are too smart, I tested it but autocomplete simulates keypress quite efficiently... too bad :-/

Comment: That was my suspicion but thought it was worth an ask.  As a solution, I've had to just open up some of my validators, and use the info boxes very to denote the requirements, such as a "10-digit phone number".  At least that way when they violate, it's clear as to why. Also going to install a Hover handler for the button to cue the user to look back over the app to get the button to enable.  Thanks again Serge!