# validateEmail requires lowercase values?

Tags: google-apps-script

Not sure If I am missing something here but appears that when I use 'validateEmail' it requires the email address to be in lowercase.  If you run my code below and type in your name and an email address with on uppercase value it will not submit.  However, if you remove all uppercase values to lower it works fine.  Does anyone know if this is by design or perhaps a bug?

```
function doGet() {
//  // Create the signup application
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  //Create vertical panel to hold the widgets
  var panelMain = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('mainPanel');

  var lblName = app.createLabel('Name:').setId('lblName').setWidth('80px')
  .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily","Trebuchet MS")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12pt");


  var txtName = app.createTextBox().setName('txtName').setId('txtName').setWidth('300px')
  .setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#ffbb00")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily", "Trebuchet MS")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "12pt");

  var lblEmail = app.createLabel('Email:').setId('lblEmail').setWidth('80px')
  .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily","Trebuchet MS")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12pt");

  var txtEmail = app.createTextBox().setName('txtEmail').setId('txtEmail').setWidth('300px')
  .setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#ffbb00")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily", "Trebuchet MS")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "12pt");

  var lblRequiredEmail = app.createLabel('*').setId('lblRequiredEmail');
  var lblRequiredName = app.createLabel('*').setId('lblRequiredName');
  var lblStatus = app.createLabel("Sign up to receive specials and promotions.").setId('lblStatus')
  .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily","Trebuchet MS")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12pt");

  var btnSubmit = app.createButton("Submit").setId("btnSubmit").setWidth("120px")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily", "Trebuchet MS")
  .setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "12pt")


  var gridMain = app.createGrid(4, 3).setId('gridMain');

 gridMain.setWidget(0,0,lblName)
 .setWidget(0,1,txtName)
 .setWidget(0, 2, lblRequiredName)
 .setWidget(1, 0,lblEmail)
 .setWidget(1, 1,txtEmail)
  .setWidget(1,2,lblRequiredEmail)
 .setWidget(2,1,btnSubmit);

  panelMain.add(lblStatus).add(gridMain);




  //Create server handler for when user submits the information
  var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('Signup')
 .validateEmail(txtEmail)
 .validateLength(txtName,1,500)
 .addCallbackElement(panelMain);


  var validateEmail = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotEmail(txtEmail)
  .forTargets(txtEmail).setStyleAttribute("color", "red")
  .forTargets(lblRequiredEmail).setVisible(true)
  .setText('Invalid Email')
  .setStyleAttribute("color", "red");


  var validateName = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotLength(txtName,1,500)
  .forTargets(txtName).setStyleAttribute("color", "red")
  .forTargets(lblRequiredName).setVisible(true)
  .setText('Please Enter Name')
  .setStyleAttribute("color", "red");

 btnSubmit.addClickHandler(serverHandler).addClickHandler(validateEmail).addClickHandler(validateName);
   app.add(panelMain);
  return app;
}

function Signup(thisForm)
{

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var txtName = thisForm.parameter.txtName;
  var txtEmail = thisForm.parameter.txtEmail;
  var lblStatus = thisForm.parameter.lblStatus;

  //Other code to save to data store
 ////
  app.getElementById("lblStatus").setText('Thanks for signing!');
  app.getElementById('gridMain').setVisible(false);

  return app;

 // return app2; //Everything is working fine right now 

}
```

Comment: honestly I though that email adresses had to be in lowerCase but I checked in the [RFC2822 description](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822) and capitals are indeed allowed... This is a question for a Googler ;-)

Comment: It seems that issue [1799](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1799&can=1&q=validateEmail&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) treats this validation. Though it was declared invalid. But I really couldn't get [it](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/dev-test/dev-test-upper-lower) to work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that validateEmail has worked this way in past. I'd tried the solution in [Is there a way to turn off Auto Fill for users when filling out a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124539/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-auto-fill-for-users-when-filling-out-a-form) before, and I'm pretty sure that it took mixed case. @Serge might remember.

[Issue 1799: validation functions in google apps script is not working properly](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1799) had been reported then closed in Sept 2012 because it was too broad. I think that opens the door to report this specific problem.

For an alternative that does its own email validation, and handles mixed case, have a look at this Apps Script Tutorial on [Email Validation](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/user-interface/validation).

Comment: Agree I decided to open an issue [2317](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2317&thanks=2317&ts=1358565483) specificly for the Email validation. It really does not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and opening up an issue.  I will use the other methods for email validation.